# Get visitor location with PHP/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

when a user visits my website I want to get his/her location in order to show a map centered around that location.

Is it possible to do so with Laravel or Javascript?

For example if my user is visiting from Madrid, Spain I want to get a string back like "Madrid, Spain" or similar.

What would be the best way?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tons of services that gives you exact user location by their IP.
For example: https://ipstack.com/ or https://ipapi.co/

You can find more [here](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk031lVoSXbIqjIeRq9k6mh7-MWPmhA%3A1587500484653&ei=xFWfXomuJ5GrgAbs9KqADA&q=get%20location%20by%20IP%20api&oq=get%20location%20by%20IP%20api&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yAggAMgYIABAIEB4yBggAEAgQHjoECAAQRzoICAAQCBAHEB46CAgAEAgQDRAeUPdcWKaEAWD5hQFoAXADeACAAecBiAG_GpIBBjAuMTAuOJgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiJoN-TrProAhWRFcAKHWy6CsAQ4dUDCAw&uact=5) or make do it custom by reading [this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)

Hope this helps you